# Adding a Flask user login requirement

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I am using Flask-Security, which in turn uses Flask-Login. I have a site which requires that a user both confirm their email address AND subsequently be approved by an admin. Without both of these things, I don't want the user to be able to use the site.

I've turned on `SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE` and the email with the confirmation token is being sent correctly. I've set `SECURITY_POST_CONFIRM_VIEW`, and the user is directed to the right view once they click the confirmation link in the email. However, *the user is logged in* [as part of the confirmation process](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/4376a1ef136ffdfe5e0f0031a1c7a5c6812dfbca/flask_security/views.py#L234). I don't want the user to have access until they are approved by an admin. (Interestingly, [this line is not present](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/a401fb47018fbbbe0b899ea55afadfd0e3cd847a/flask_security/views.py#L233) in the `develop` branch.)

I can think of four ways to get around this, and none are particularly appealing:

1. Allow the user to log in after confirmation, but decorate every `login_required` view with a function which checks the user's permissions and sends them to an error page if they aren't allowed. I already have 2 of these, and I'd prefer to avoid adding a third to every view. Plus, it feels wrong to allow login when the user can't use the site until they're approved.
2. Turn off `SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE` and email/confirm the token myself. This will require copying a lot of code and the chances of an error are higher than I would like. And are there perhaps other ways a user can login which would get around this check? Say through the password reset flow? Or if a future admin turned on passwordless login with tokens?
3. Monkey patch Flask-Security's [`login_user`](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/4376a1ef136ffdfe5e0f0031a1c7a5c6812dfbca/flask_security/utils.py#L64) or Flask-Login's [`login_user`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/fd2f3f993b6b74761c9a57a0a792e66a239b1195/flask_login/utils.py#L142) to do my check. Seems quite hacky, and I don't know how to ensure that my patch is installed before any other code connects to the original function.
4. Fork one of these libraries and insert a callback which I can implement in my code. Sledgehammer, meet nut. Plus maintainability issues. Unless perhaps I managed to get a PR accepted.

I hope there is another answer I'm overlooking. This can't be that uncommon a setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, the solution was MUCH easier than I feared. UserMixin has an `is_active` property which gets consulted at the very beginning of Flask-Login's `login_user`. So my code simply looks like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, Base):
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return (super(UserMixin, self).is_active and not self.has_role('pending'))
```

Now no user can sign in who has a 'pending' role.

Comment: Hi I'm facing the same issue. Just wondering how did you set the user role to pending during registration.

Comment: I have a subclass of `RegisterForm` which I'm using in the `/register/` view. I need this because my form has extra fields. But it means I need to create my user manually anyway. (You can do the same.) [Here's my code.](https://gist.github.com/nk9/81a1e3674b9efe6314e07d715d06cd4c)